# What area of physics discusses things breaking?

Tags: kinematics

My background is in Mathematics and I wanted to know more about destruction physics such as what equations govern destruction and how to simulate them with a computer.

Googling 'destruction physics' and 'physics equations for destruction' have left me with no useful answers.

I would like to simulate the destruction of things like wood and bricks and even mountains if possible.

Comment: Materials science does. Not so much physics per se.

Comment: Deformation and fracture mechanics. See Hertzberg’s text of the same name for coverage of engineering materials.

Comment: Fracture mechanics is the first area that came to mind, but more generally destruction is so broad it doesn't really narrow things down. For example combustion, explosions, ballistic impacts etc tend to be multidisciplinary. perhaps you need to search for simulation of explosions, or simulation of a specific type of event.

Comment: Thanks, fracture mechanics looks like the right place to begin my search.

Comment: Also worth taking a look at [catastrophe theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory) - relating to sudden states of disequilibrium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of materials science is what you are after. Within that field are detailed studies of how different materials respond to stresses, shock, and sometimes explosions. This includes *strength of materials*, *fracture mechanics*, and *plasticity mechanisms*.